# Exportar tabela HTML para Excel mantendo os estilos

Tags: html, microsoft-excel

Gostaria de saber como faço para exportar uma tabela do meu código html para excel mantendo a formatação (cores, bordas, etc). Estou utilizando a seguinte função:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function fnExcelReport() {
    var tab_text = '<html xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">';
    tab_text = tab_text + '<head><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet>';

    tab_text = tab_text + '<x:Name>Results</x:Name>';

    tab_text = tab_text + '<x:WorksheetOptions><x:Panes></x:Panes></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet>';
    tab_text = tab_text + '</x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml></head><body>';

    tab_text = tab_text + "<table border='2px'; >";
    tab_text = tab_text + $('.biocompar').html() + $("#janelares1a").html()+ $("#janelares5a").html();
    tab_text = tab_text + '</table></body></html>';

    var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';

    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

    if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) {
        if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
            var blob = new Blob([tab_text], {
                type: "application/csv;charset=utf-8;"
            });
            navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, 'Biorefinery WebTool Results.xls');
        }
    } else {
        $('#test').attr('href', data_type + ', ' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));
        $('#test').attr('download', 'Biorefinery WebTool Results.xls');
    }

}
</script>
```

Mas quando eu ativo a função ela apenas envia os dados da tabela e cria a planilha, mas sem formatação nenhuma (por exemplo essa aqui de baixo). Como aplicar o CSS no Excel também? Obrigado!

```
td{
    width:30ch;
    height:3ch;
    background-color:#f0f8ff;
    border: 2px solid #151c14;
    font-family: "Muli";
    line-height: 5ch;
    color:#000;
    text-indent: 0.5em;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;

}
```

Comment: Conseguiu reolver?

Answer (score 1):

Já apanhei muito com isso há alguns anos, a única solução foi declarar os estilos inline mesmo.

Lembro que tinha encontrado uma restrição onde Excel só reconhece uma classe por elemento e no caso não adiantaria você criar uma `td{}`, teria que ser como `.nome{}` e estar declarada como a única classe do elemento `<td class="nome">`. Se houver mais de uma ele desconsidera todas.

E mesmo assim, não espere um grande enriquecimento no visual, afinal de contas o Excel não é um browser html, tente limitar-se ao básico... Como se estivesse criando o estilo para um E-mail ou Word.

Ps.: Vou procurar as fontes onde tinha pesquisado e incluir na resposta.

Comment: Puxa que pena, mas muito obrigado mesmo!